# Map Publisher to another publishers sequentially and handle errors for each step separately (or skip) in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, error-handling, combine, flatmap, sink

Code:

```
import Combine

func login() -> Future<Token, Error> { ... }
func updateImage() -> Future<Status, Never> { ... }
func getProfile() -> Future<Profile, Error> { ... }
```

I need to perform something like this (sequential actions):

```
login()
.catch { error in
  ... //handle error
}
.flatMap { token in
  ...//handle login results
  return updateImage()
}
.catch { _ in
  ... //skip error
}
.flatMap { 
  ... //handle updateImage results
  return getProfile()
}
.sink(...) //handle getProfile results and errors
```

The problem is `Combine` has misleading types inside `flatMap` and `catch`.

Tried to return `Empty` inside catch blocks:

```
return Empty<String, CustomError>(completeImmediately: true)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

But I don't understand if it stops producing errors in `sink` section. And is it a correct approach for my task in general?

Comment: "The problem is Combine has misleading types inside flatMap and catch." What are you talking about? What are the "misleading types"? And why is this a problem? Does it produce any errors at all?

Comment: This might help: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html

Comment: @Sweeper `map`/`flatMap` is ok. `catch` - how to stop executing or continue with another type like void? The official documentation shows how to use `Just` to map error to value of type specified by publisher only

Comment: @matt thanks for a link but it doesn't include any info about how to handle error.

Comment: It is completely unclear what your question is, so I have to guess. I was addressing your "misleading types". The catch page is https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsErrorHandlers/operatorscatch.html. I don't think you need your hand held to navigate a book so I'll leave you to it. Just click some links until you learn what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain multiple of these independent `Future`s, and handle errors in each step, you can follow the pattern:

```
future().map { result in
    // handle the future's result
    // this implicitly returns Void, turning it into a publisher of Void
}
.catch { error in
    // handle error...

    // in the case of an error,
    // if you want the pipeline to continue, return Just(())
    // if you want the pipeline to stop, return Empty()
}
```

Each of these is a publisher that either publishes one `()`, or no values at all. Then you can chain multiple of these together with `flatMap`:

```
let cancellable = login().map { token in
    // handle login result...
    return ()
}
.catch { error in
    // handle login error...
    return Just(())
}
.flatMap { _ in
    updateImage().map { status in
        // handle updateImage results...
    }
    // no need for .catch here because updateImage doesn't fail
}
.flatMap { _ in
    getProfile().map { profile in
        // handle getProfile results...
    }.catch { error in
        // handle getProfile errors...
        return Just(())
    }
}.sink { completion in
    // handle completion
} receiveValue: { _ in
    // you will only recieve a () here
}
```

To help the compiler figure out the types more quickly, or even at all, you should add explicit return types and/or `eraseToAnyPublisher()` where appropriate.

As Dávid Pásztor's answer said, if `login` and so on are `async` methods instead, this chaining is built directly into the language. You can write a "chain" in the same way as you write sequential statements.

```
func login() async throws -> Token { ... }
func updateImage() async -> Status { ... }
func getProfile() async throws -> Profile { ... }

func asyncChain() async {
    do {
        let token = try await login()
        // handle login results...
    } catch {
        // handle login error...
    }
    
    let status = await updateImage()
    // handle updateImage results...
    
    do {
        let profile = try await getProfile()
        // handle getProfile results...
    } catch {
        // handle getProfile error...
    }
}
```

Comment: it not suitable for me but at least with your help I found a mistake in my code - `catch` precedes `flatMap` so `catch` should return a publisher with the same value type as publisher obtained in the previous chain steps.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with `Future`s and want to chain several one off async calls after each other, you're much better off using `async` methods than Combine.

Unfortunately Combine has no type-level support for `Publisher`s that only ever emit 1x and then always complete. `Future` tries to achieve this, but as soon as you apply any operators to a `Future`, you get a `Publisher`, so you cannot build a Combine pipeline that guarantees that each of its steps can only emit 1x.

On the other hand, `async` methods achieve this exact goal.

```
func login() async throws -> Token { ... }
func updateImage() async -> Status { ... }
func getProfile() async throws -> Profile { ... }

do {
  let token: Token
  do {
    token = try await login() 
  } catch {
    token = // assign a default value
  }
  let status = try await updateImage()
  let profile = try await getProfile()
} catch {
  // handle profile errors
}
```

Comment: Though I agree that async methods are more suitable, I disagree with "so you cannot build a Combine pipeline that guarantees that each of its steps can only emit 1x" Each Combine operator is documented and does a very specific thing. Why can't it be guaranteed? Statically analyse what operators one has used, and in some cases there will be a guarantee.

Comment: @Sweeper documentation and compile-time guarantees that are built into the type system are very different things. Static analysis using 3rd party tools again, is a very different thing than language-level support.